# Prove $\det(T^*)=\det(T)$ using exterior algebta

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. $T^*:V^*\to V^*$ is  the transpose of  $T$ (i.e., $T^*(\lambda)=\lambda\circ T$). I want to find a coordinate-free proof of $\det(T^*)=\det(T)$. Does anyone know a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** This follows almost immediately from the [coordinate-free characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Exterior_algebra) of $\det$: The map $T$ determines a canonical map $$\det T : \Lambda^n V^* \to \Lambda^n V^*$$
defined by extending the map $v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n \mapsto T(v_1) \wedge \cdots \wedge T(v_n)$ by linearity; here $n := \dim V$. (The existence of this map---and its well-definedness---are guaranteed by the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Universal_property).) Since $\dim \Lambda^n V^* = 1$, $\det T$ is just multiplication by some constant in the base field of $V$, and this is precisely the determinant.

> **Additional hint** More-or-less by construction $\det (T^*) = (\det T)^*$, but $\det T$ and $(\det T)^*$ are adjoint maps from a $1$-dimensional vector space to itself, so they are both multiplication maps by the same constant.

Comment: How to extend the map? There is not a canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$.

Comment: The extension is by linearity (I've edited my answer to make this explicit, and added an additional hint). I don't see how your other remark applies to the situation.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. There is a canonical isomorphism between $(\Lambda^n V)^*$ and $\Lambda^n V^*$, which enable us to identify $(\Lambda^n T)^*$ and $\Lambda^n T^*$.

Comment: Great, you're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $V$ is $n$-dimensional, the space of $n$-alternating forms defined on  on $V$ has dimension 1 and $det$ is a generator. Let $f(A)=det(A^*)$ $A$ is multilinear and alternating. Thus there exists $c$ such that $det(A^*)=cdet(A)$. In particular, if $A=I_n$ the matrix of the identity map, $I^*=I$ thus $det(I^*)=cdet(I)$ implies $c=1$ and for every $A$, $det(A^*)=det(A)$.